# HTML5 and CSS3 - How to Make Videos Side by Side and responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 3x3 layout style of videos on my website. I have them responsive but I can't figure out how the middle can be centered in between the left and right video and how to put space in between them. Also, I want some margin on the right and left so they don't hit the border of the webpage. Here is the HTML and CSS:
HTML:

```
<div class="video-layout">
<div class="video">
<div id="vid-left">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="vid-mid">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="vid-right">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-layout {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#vid-left {
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}
#vid-mid {

}
#vid-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: try putting `float:left;width:33%;` on each of `#vid-left`, `#vid-mid` and `#vid-right` ?

Comment: Also remove `position: absolute;` on `.video iframe`

Comment: Ok sweet, now it just needs space

Comment: You can put `padding:5px;box-sizing:border-box;` on `vid-left`,`vid-mid` and `vid-right` to give it some padding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at this: [https://jsfiddle.net/w1mmLz4h/](https://jsfiddle.net/w1mmLz4h/1/)

CSS:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-layout {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#vid-left {
    float: left;
    padding:5px;
    width:33%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#vid-mid {
    float: left;
    padding:5px;
    width:33%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#vid-right {
    float: left;
    padding:5px;
    width:33%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="video-layout">
<div class="video">
<div id="vid-left">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="vid-mid">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="vid-right">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You nailed like the basic layout, it just needs the spacing, would I use margins, padding, and they need like one on the left, one in the middle, and one in the right.

Comment: @DannieDella How about now?

Comment: @DannieDella Adjust padding as needed.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. I am going to try to figure out how to put videos under those and do the same thing and make them a little bigger. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, how does the width % work? I'm adjusting the width % to make it bigger and it looks bad. Do I also need to include a height %? Thanks

Comment: @DannieDella How does it look bad? The percentages should add up and stay under 100%

Comment: It is wide but slim when I adjust the %s. At the moment, I am currently trying to make them like medium-sized videos so it isn't tiny. I also want them a universal size :P

Comment: If you want all of them to be larger you should increase the `max-width` of `.video-layout`. They are currently constrained at 500px

Answer (score 1):

- Used OP's classic responsive video rules then scaled everything roughly at 30%.
- Used flexbox to keep an equal amount of space between each video and the screen's edges.
- Applied the defaults I use normally.

It's very responsive, shrink it, enlarge it, call it bad names it just keeps chugging along. All it needs is a simple media query to make it stack vertically when displayed on a phone/tablet portrait oriented....

.... Ok I added a media query for mobile portrait orientation. When testing it, go to dev tools and use the phone emulator, or better yet look at this in a phone ;-)

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>35761650</title>
  <style>
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 500 16px/1.428'Raleway';
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      background: black;
      color: yellow;
    }
    .video {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      height: 16vh;
      width: 30vw;
    }
    .video iframe {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 56.25%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .videoFrame {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      width: 100vw;
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 12vh 0;
    }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
      .videoFrame {
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .video {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        height: 0;
        width: 100vw;
      }
      .video iframe {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="videoFrame">
    <div class="video">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qdIdPBIF6MU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this embed code, all your worries will be solved.

If you have uploaded videos to YouTube or other sites.
First, embed them and copy the code they provided.
Then place the embed code of your first video instad the line that says "**Place your video code here**" in my code.

Then place the code for your second video next to the same line in the other section of my code.

Putting the URL of the video directly will not work.

Ones Your video code are added to my code.

Copy and paste everything into a section of your site where you can embed the codes.

That will place your videos side by side.
Dont forget to adjust the video sizes in my code to fit the size of videod you want.

<iframe width="128" height="72"
**place your embed video code here**

<iframe width="128" height="72"
**place your embed video code here**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).